# getting options 204 while using cloudinary api resources

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloudinary, http-status-code-204

I am using cloudinary to fetch my images and everything works fine but it sends a 204 preflight res when using cloudinary and when i remove cloudinary logic it works normal.

login Controller

```
    const gender = await getGender(username);
    
    const profileImage = await getProfileImage(gender);

    //creating a new user
    const newUser = new User({
      username,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      gender,
      profileImage,
    });

    //saving the user to the database
    await newUser.save();
    console.log("hello");
    //returning the new created user in the response
    return res.status(201).json({ message: "Registration Successful" });
```

getPofileImage function

```
export const getProfileImage = async (gender: string) => {
  try {
    // fetching image according to the user's gender
    const response = await cloudinary.api.resources({
      type: "upload",
      prefix: `e-com/images/${gender}`,
    });
    return response.resources[
      Math.floor(Math.random() * response.resources.length)
    ].url;
  } catch (error) {
    return "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FGCpQkBXMAIqA6d?format=jpg&name=large";
  }
};
```

I was expecting a 201 response with {message:"Registration Successful"} but instead of that i am getting 204 with nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `getProfileImage`, you are using `cloudinary.api.resources`. This is an [Admin API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api) that is designed for back-end operation and also rate limited.

Could you explain the use case a little more? Perhaps you could use [tagging](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/managing_assets#tagging_assets) with [client side list API](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/advanced_url_delivery_options#client_side_asset_lists) and achieve the same result? When you do this, you get the following advantages:

- Requests are not rate limited.
- Cloudinary can change the CORS policy if needed to allow all requests.
- Responses are cached. So it will have a better performance as well.

Comment: Thanks I got the answer i set timeout on axios client side that's why request was not fulfilling